# greatest common divisor

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How can I find the greatest common divisor of x and y?

[image]

I know the algorithm but I can't figure out how to use it on numbers with powers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\ \ \ \gcd(p^a q^b\cdots,\, p^A q^B\cdots)\, =\, p^{\min(a,A)}\! q^{\min(b,B)}\!\cdots\, $ for distinct primes $\,p,q,\,\ldots$

**Proof** $\ $ By existence and uniqueness of prime factorizations,  divisors $\,d\,$ have form

$\qquad\quad  d\mid\, n\, = p^a q^b\cdots\! \iff d = p^\alpha q^\beta\cdots,\, \alpha \le a,\ \beta \le b,\,\ldots$

$\qquad\quad  d\mid N\! = p^A q^B\cdots\!\! \iff\! d = p^\alpha q^\beta\cdots,\, \alpha \le A,\ \beta \le B,\,\ldots$

$\begin{align}{\rm Thus}\ \ d\mid n,N\iff&\ \alpha \le a,A,\ \ {\rm and}\ \ \beta \le b,B,\ 
\ldots\\ \iff &\ \alpha  \color{#c00}\le \min(a,A),\,\beta  \color{#c00}\le \min(b,B),\ \ldots\end{align}$

The *greatest* common divisor $\,d\,$ arises by choosing the greatest possible prime powers above, i.e. we should choose $\,\ \alpha \color{#c00}= \min(a,A),\ \,\beta  \color{#c00}= \min(b,B),\,\ldots$

Answer (score 3):

You should not use the Euclidean algorithm, but rather the fact that if you have 
$$x=\prod_{i=1}^r p_i^{r_i} \text{ and } y=\prod_{i=1}^r p_i^{s_i}$$
with distinct primes $p_i$, then the GCD is given by 
$$\prod_{i=1}^r p_i^{\min(r_i,s_i)}.$$

Answer (score 2):

From x and y as you have laid them out:
The lesser power of 2 is  3,
The lesser power of 5 is  0,
The lesser power of 7 is  0,
The lesser power of 11 is  7,
The lesser power of 13 is  0,
The lesser power of 17 is  9,
The lesser power of 19 is  0.
The product of all these lesser powers is the number you seek.
Bear in mind that the 0th power evaluates to 1. (But you knew that.)

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way. $2^2$ is a factor or both, so it's a factor of the GCD. $2^3$ is too. However, $2^4$ is a factor of only one. Thus $2^3$ is the largest factor of the GCD involving 2. Now do that for each prime factor to find the GCD, since other primes clearly won't divide it. Does that clarify the motivation for quid's method?